Tweaks --> Windows Title Option which under fonts not displaying
I am experiencing an issue with GNOME Tweaks on my Ubuntu system. I am trying to set the San Francisco Pro font for my system, but I am unable to find the "Window Title" font option in the Fonts section of GNOME Tweaks



Try setting None under Hinting and then set Subpixel (for LCD screens) under  Antialiasing
